# How to find highest value from database matching a pattern using EF Core 2.1?

Tags: c#, .net-core, ef-core-2.2, .net-core-2.2

I am using Entity Framework Core 2.1 to store a table called "Equipment" in SQL. That table has a column called "Label". I have a class called `Equipment` with Label as string property.

That Label property sometimes can have a pattern of `#[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]` from user input.

How do I find the highest "Label" value matching the pattern above from the "Equipment" table using EF Core 2.1 fast and clean from SQL table?

```
var myContext = CreateDbContext();
string resultIdentifier;

        // if there is any item in the equipment table
        if (myContext.equipment.Any()) {
            var regexStr = @"^[#]+(0-9{5})$";  //TODO: how to create this regex string correctly?

            // find for any matching pattern in label column using regex
            var listFound = myContext.equipment.Where(mp => Regex.IsMatch(mp.Label, regexStr)).ToList();

            if (listFound.Any()) {
                //TODO: how to find the maximum from the pattern?
            }
            else {
                _logger.Trace("No highest label is found because no matched pattern is found.");
                resultIdentifier = null;
            }
        }
        else {
            _logger.Trace("No highest label is found because no entry in equipment table.");
            resultIdentifier = null;
        }
```

1) How to create a correct Regex search string matching pattern `#[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]`?

2) Is Regex the best approach to look for the highest label pattern?

3) How to find the highest label pattern from SQL table using EF Core method?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the regex will be inefficient. EF cannot convert the Regex.IsMatch to a corresponding SQL expression, so it will first fetch the entire equipment table, then apply the regex to each row in the table.

Instead, SQL Server has regex-like patterns and wildcards which may be used within a query using [LIKE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

Consider the following:

```sql
DECLARE @foo TABLE (
    label varchar(10) null
)

INSERT @foo
SELECT '#12345'  -- 'Lowest'
UNION 
SELECT '#99999'  -- 'Highest'
UNION 
SELECT '#999999' -- 'Too Many Characters
UNION
SELECT '#123'    -- 'Not Enough Characters' 
UNION 
SELECT '#abcde1' -- 'Not the Right Characters'
UNION
SELECT '12345'   -- 'No Leading #'
```

```
SELECT label 
  FROM @foo 
 WHERE label LIKE '[#][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
```

will return rows matching your pattern (the # character itself is a wildcard, so it is wrapped in brackets to indicate it is a literal):

```
label
=====
#12345
#99999
```

```
SELECT TOP 1 label 
  FROM @foo 
 WHERE label LIKE '[#][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
 ORDER BY label desc
```

will order your results from highest to lowest:

```
label
=====
#99999
#12345
```

and adding TOP 1 will return the first row:

```
label
=====
#99999
```

There are a few ways to use this in EF Core, but the easiest is to simply use a [raw SQL query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql):

```
string sql = @"SELECT TOP 1 * 
  FROM @foo 
 WHERE label LIKE '[#][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
 ORDER BY label desc";

var foundRows = myContext.equipment
    .FromSql(sql)
    .ToList();

if (foundRows.FirstOrDefault() != null) 
{
   //...do something...
}
```